# How to jump to next break point in IntelliJ?

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea, ide

How can I jump to the next breakpoint in IntelliJ, as I can in Visual Studio by pressing <kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: If you go to `Help` and choose `Default Keymap Reference` you'll get a really nice overview of all the shortcuts in a PDF format. Print it out and put it next to you.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

While in debug mode, and between two breakpoints, hit the <kbd>F9</kbd> key.

Comment: If F9 is a bit far from 1-hand on mouse, you can re-assign and find keyboard shortcuts in Settings > Keymap

Answer (score 39):

AFAIK, there is no direct F5 like in Visual Studio to jump to the next breakpoint without cursor pointing. The closest is the **ALT+F9 that jumps to the cursor**.

For quick reference, the most used debugging keyboard shortcuts are:

- <kbd>F8</kbd> Step over
- <kbd>F7</kbd> Step into
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd> Smart step into
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Step out
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> Run to cursor
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> Evaluate expression
- <kbd>F9</kbd> *(Mac: Cmd + ALT + R)* Resume program
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> *(Mac: Cmd + F8)* Toggle breakpoint
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F8</kbd> *(Mac: Cmd + Shift + F8)* View breakpoints

To note that there are some keyboard shortcut differences between Mac and Win/Linux. Full references to PDF cheatsheets below.

- Mac keymap: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard_Mac.pdf
- Win/Linux keymap: https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/docs/IntelliJIDEA_ReferenceCard.pdf

Answer (score 4):

In Windows use <kbd>F9</kbd> key to move next debug