# Search through breakpoints in IntelliJ like Navigate > Breakpoints in ReSharper

Tags: intellij-idea

ReSharper has the ability to [search through breakpoints](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Navigation_and_Search_Navigating_Breakpoints.html). Has anyone created or come across similar functionality for IntelliJ Idea? It would extremely useful to have the same functionality.

> To find a breakpoint, start typing the name of the containing project, class, member, or contents of the line where the breakpoint is defined. The input field is case-insensitive and allows you to type any parts of the above-mentioned items separated by whitespaces:
>   [image: Blockquote]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to jump to next break point in IntelliJ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962122/how-to-jump-to-next-break-point-in-intellij)

Comment: @PetrRastegaev I don't want to jump to the next breakpoint. I want to *search* through all of the breakpoints using a string to find the breakpoint containing the text that I'm searching for. See the second to last bullet in step 3 of the link I provided.

Comment: Please vote for this issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183480

Comment: Thanks @BasLeijdekkers, I didn't see that on youtrack when I was looking. If you'd like, post a link to your issue as an answer and I'll accept it with the hope that it will be implemented some day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible, but there is a feature request open for it: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-183480
Please vote for it and hopefully it will be implemented.