# Jump between highlights in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way to navigate up and down the highlights as in the screenshot?

I read the article here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/navigating-through-the-source-code.html but couldn't find what I'm looking for

Basic usage is I just want to sprinkle a bunch of highlights around the code and be able to jump between them using a shortcut.

I know that an alternative would be to use the favorites, but I want to see if it can be done using highlights.

I'm on a Mac.

[image]

Comment: By "highlights" do you mean *breakpoints*?

Comment: @jonrsharpe oops my mistake, I did more research now that I figured out that it's a breakpoint and it looks like there's no such option :( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15962122/how-to-jump-to-next-break-point-in-intellij

Comment: Can't you use bookmarks instead? I don't think a breakpoint on a class definition or field does anything anyway (unless you posted this as a random example).

Comment: @Jeto yep, i should be using bookmarks instead, I just liked the visual aspect of it (the highlight really sticks out). But it doesn't make sense to use breakpoints, that's a valid point

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment above, you're using these breakpoints as a kind of visible bookmark within your code. However, IntelliJ does have a [Bookmarks](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Navigation_and_Search__Bookmarks.html) feature.

I would therefore suggest to simply alter the way they appear so they stick out more:

- Go to `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | General`
- On the right pane, expand/select `Editor | Bookmarks`
- Adjust the background and/or foreground colors on the right (and more if needed)

Here's an example with funky bookmarks (pardon my light theme):

[image]

You can then navigate between them using:

`Navigate | Bookmarks | Previous Bookmark`

`Navigate | Bookmarks | Next Bookmark`

Answer (score 1):

> I just want to sprinkle a bunch of highlights around the code and be able to jump between them using a shortcut.

`Navigate` > `Back` and `Navigate` > `Forward` should work ideally in that case.